# Auto-populate Forms From CurrentRecord - MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access

Just started Access last week so I'm not great with its coding and I only know what I have needed to so far.

I'm at a point where I have sub-tables of sorts; in particular we are databasing some Bathrooms which contain Sinks, Dispensers, Mirrors etc. Each contained item has a crap-ton of info and there can be many of them, so they each have their own table (tblSinks, tblMirrors etc, along with tblBathrooms).

Each item will be associated with a bathroom (many to one; items to bathroom). I need to know what is the best, most accepted and used way to link the forms in such a way that when editing a bathroom in the form, there is a tab with buttons linking to the other forms (btnOpenMirrorForm type thing).

What I would like is the best practise for:

1. Opening the Form (if there's anything special about it, otherwise using Design's button wizard)
2. Automatically populating the item's "AssociatedBathroomID" based on the ID of their current record in the bathroom form
3. Ensureing sufficient information is displayed to reassure the user that they are creating a Mirror WITHIN the bathroom they wanted (because record navigation I can do myself, but does need to be implemented)
4. When the btnOpenMirrorForm is pressed, it should open to a new record (think of it as a "Add an Item to this bathroom" type button)

Before you say, I have tried looking into it. There are many ways, and some may work, but I'd like to know what is the best way; this definitely seems like something that should be common. I'm not opposed to subforms either, but as I've said there's a lot of information and this ultimately is going onto a Tablet PC's screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should make sure your tables have proper relationships. E.g. one bathroom can multiple items where an item can be a sink, mirror etc.

Batrhoom then would have a one to many relation with Items. Each item in items can be chosen from a list of sinks, mirrors etc using lookup tables. So once a sing has been added to the database, that sink can be used many times again.

1. Opening the form: The wizard button is sufficient for opening a form. However there are some more parameters you can supply when opening a form. Advise to use the wizard's code and take a look at it and see what more options there are (for example opening a form as dialog, modal etc)
2. Not clear what you mean with this
3. In such cases where a Thing (Bathroom) has multiple sub-things and space is limited I use a tab-control. The upper part of the form then contains the Bathroom info, the lower part has a tab-control with a tab for each of the sub-things... Inside the tab you can place a subform for that. The subform can be linked to the main form, and then Access will take care of the correct linking if new sub-form items are added.
4. It is possible to open forms in data-input, but if you use a form- subform principle the subform can show all data that belongs to the mainform item.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for; because there can be one or many of EACH type of item, having tabs doesn't work without lots of subforms. I ended up using buttons from the "Bathroom" form which automatically open only "Item1" records which correspond to the currently open Bathroom. I can't answer my own question yet but the code was basically "Open a new form, in the new form's Form_Open use the Forms!frmBathroom!ID to fill the AssociatedBathroom and show the user only records which have THAT bathroom as the AssociatedBathroom". Simple algorithm, works well.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know your requirements, nor the expectation that your boss (?) has from the database. I would have done it much simpeler... 1 table for bathrooms, and one related table for items in that bathroom, giving you a nice simple userfriendly option of a form with 1 subform where the user can do most of the things. For your solution, I can only advice to be carefull and test it what happens if the users starts playing with the access menu, filters etc.

Comment: Honestly I think your answer, now that I understand how Access does subforms, was the better way to go. I've already got it all set up as seperate windows now, but you've got the answer. It's a very simple data entry database, no user searching and few reports, so filters menus etc are being disabled.

Comment: Sometimes when you just started with access, it may be difficult to see the simple solutions through all the options.